# Showing that $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space, $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $\Sigma$ with
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=X,$$
and $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function such that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the function $f·χ_{A_n}$, where $χ_{A_n}$ is the characteristic function of $A_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$, is $\Sigma$-measurable. I want to show that $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

I know if I want to show that $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, then I need to show that

$$\forall B\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}), f^{-1}(B)\in\Sigma.$$

I started with using the fact that $f·χ_{A_n}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable and broke this up into two cases. Case 1 where $B\in A_n$ and case 2 where $B\in A_n^c$

For the first case, since $B\in A_n$ by the definition of the characteristic function we have,

\begin{align}
f^{-1}·χ_{A_n}(B)&\in\Sigma\\
f^{-1}(B)·χ_{A_n}(B)&\in\Sigma\\
f^{-1}(B)·1 &\in\Sigma\\
f^{-1}(B)&\in\Sigma.
\end{align}

Which is what we wanted to show. Now the only trouble I have is showing that $f^{-1}(B)\in\Sigma$ for the second case since if $B\in A_n^c$ then we have,
\begin{align}
f^{-1}·χ_{A_n}(B)&\in\Sigma\\
f^{-1}(B)·χ_{A_n}(B)&\in\Sigma\\
f^{-1}(B)·0 &\in\Sigma\\
0&\in\Sigma.
\end{align}
Which doesn't tell me much about $f^{-1}(B)$. I'm not sure where to go with my proof from here and how to use the fact that the countable union of the sequence $A_n$ partitions $X$. Any hints will be very much appeciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof makes no sense. $B\in A_n$ does not have any meaning. $B$ is a set of real numbers and $A_n$ is a subset of $X$. What does it mean to say that one set belongs to another? Perhaps you have misunderstood what $A_n$'s are.

The proof is very simple. $f^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_n [A_n \cap(f\chi_{A_n})^{-1}(B)]$ and so  $f^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma$.